# Extjs panel loadmask not working on chrome

Tags: extjs

I have a panel and on click on a button I am calling a Ajax call. on firefox I could see the loadmask on panel but on chrome it is not working. Even I create a separate mask object before Ajax call but it only shows after Ajax call complete. I could show/hide mask using browser javascript console but somehow it is not working when Ajax call running my Ajax call is sync. and issue with chrome only.

jsfiddle.net/naveen_ramawat/6d7pyohL/2/

Comment: Down-voted for tagging this question with "java". Also, you could have provided details e.g. version of ExtJS, Firefox, Chrome, OS, could have posted a fiddle.

Comment: Hi DrakeES, I removed java tag from post, My ExtJS version 4.2.1, Chrome Version Version 43.0.2357.130 m and OS windows 7, Could not post my production code here and jsfiddle example not created right now because Ajax call is not works on cross domain. Hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Hi DarkeEs my JSfiddle is -http://jsfiddle.net/naveen_ramawat/6d7pyohL/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a mask for the whole body

```
Ext.getBody().mask('your message');
```

before ajax call and use,

```
Ext.getBody().unmask();
```

inside ajax success

Updated jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/yq8e7na8/3/

(set a timeout before asynchronos ajax call)

Comment: Yes I tried but didn't work in my case. Nothing happens during Ajax call it appears after Ajax call completed but at that time I unmasked the message.

Comment: please try a settimeout function before showing the mask

Comment: Yes trying Ext.Function.defer but result same, mask is appearing after Ajax complete.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Jsfiddle link is available, hope it will help to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi Rahul, It shows the mask after Ajax call finished, But I want mask before start Ajax call and want to hide it after Ajax call completed.

Comment: Yup, But It is a hack ;) .. Here we are delaying ajax call by 3 second and later loadmask hanged till ajax call complete :P .... But why it is not working on chrome so straight forward like it is working for firefox?

Comment: It is a synchronous ajax call,maybe our mask code is delayed by browser untill the ajax call got completed . If you want you can reduce the delay

Comment: Async:False will hold the execution of rest code. Once you get response of ajax, only then, rest of the code will execute.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code instead:

```
panel = Ext.getCmp('panel');
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(panel , {msg:"Loading..."});
myMask.show();
```

Then you can hide in the success callback function:

```
myMask.hide();
```

Comment: I know it should work but it is not working in my case. If I didn't hide mask than it appears after Ajax call complete, Don't know why it is not appearing during Ajax call.

Comment: Can you post the full code? Its hard for us to guess what u are talking about.

Comment: Here If I call Ajax after using Ext.Function.defer with some delay than initial loadmask appeared but it hang when Ajax call starts and became normal once Ajax call completed, I want to know why Ajax call hanging current loadmask?

Comment: Jsfiddle link is available, hope it will help to understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the thing:

> my Ajax call is sync. and issue with chrome only

Sync AJAX has been deprecated and Chrome actually [<s>does not process it anymore</s>](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated), showing this warning in console:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Use async AJAX.

UPDATE:

Chrome actually seems to process the sync AJAX request, however, showing the load mask falls through. It looks like, unlike Firefox, Chrome does not wait for the interface to actually render the mask before  moving onto the next bit of JavaScript code. And because the next bit is a sync AJAX call which is *freezing* everything, followed by `myMask.hide()` — we never see the mask.

To see the mask in Chrome, you can put a small delay (1 millisecond was enough on my machine) after `myMask.show();`:

```
handler(){
                var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(mypanel , {msg:"Loading..."});
                myMask.show();
                setTimeout(function(){
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/echo/js/?delay=5&js=',
                        method: 'GET',          
                        async: false
                    });
                    console.log('hiding mask');
                    myMask.hide();            
                }, 1);
            }
```

During the delay, the mask is rendered before the browser freezes making sync AJAX call.
Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6d7pyohL/4/

Comment: Yes right but here my ajax call is working and getting response from server even it is async and loadmask is hide/show manually. So why the loadmask is not displaying, loadmask is manual so it should not depend on Ajax async feature ? BTW you deserve a upvote for your last answer :P

Comment: Answer updated. It could be considered a Chrome bug if sync AJAX was not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(),{msg:"please wait..."});
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    myMask.show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    myMask.hide();
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url:"abc.php",
    async:true,
    type:"POST",
    success:function(data){

    }
});
```

instead of async:false, use **async:true**

Comment: No my requirement with ExtJs with Ajax sync request only. See the jsfiddle given in question and open in chrome and firefox to see the difference of browser behavior.